# Java code to generate random number of given(n) length

Tags: random

I have to generate a random number of length given as input (20 , 256 , 2000 , 3000). What should i use . Any best practices?

There are various methods telling range like below:

```
int rangeMin = 1,
    rangeMax = 100,
    generatedNumber;
generatedNumber = rangeMin + rand() % rangeMax;
```

but i need to work on length of interger

Comment: Have you heard of the Math.random method?

Comment: What do you mean by 'length'?

Comment: yes i am aware of math.random function but not able to use it for my problem: Requirement is if user enter n=20 the code should return random interger value like : 12234769879878979879 and if user enter n=256 code should return value of 122343435..... of 256 digits .. and should work maximum for n= 3000